# what is purpose using routes in sale order lines

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

When we enable "Choose specific routes on sales order lines (advanced)" in sale module.
After that "routes" field will show on order line in sale order
What is purpose of that routes in sale order.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Best use of route in sale order line is **Drop Shipping Delivery**.

**Drop Shipping** : Drop shipping allows to deliver the goods directly from the supplier to the customer. It means that the products does not transit through your stock.

[image]

When you Configure Advance routes then you can see Routes menu item & allow to create new routes as well.

When You select DropShippng Option then System will automatically create drop shipping route in the system.

In below example we have create sale order with two products, In one sale order line we have select **drop shipping** route.

[image]

[image]

When you confirm Purchase Order then System will create Drop shipment picking from **Supplier to Customer**.

[image]

You can find use of routes from odoo link.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/9.0/inventory/routes/concepts/use_routes.html

This may help you.